# How do I manage to get my swedish letters

Tags: shapefile, r, ggplot2, font

I am trying to do the map in ´ggplot2´ in ´R´. I use this function from `rgdal` package:

```
mapa <- readOGR(dsn=path.expand("C:/~/SWE_adm_shp"),layer="SWE_adm2")
```

than I do:

```
fortify(mapa)


ggplot(mapa, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group)) +
  geom_polygon(fill = "blue", col = "white") +
  coord_map()
```

It works fine but when I look at the

```
head(mapa)
```

I see that the names of the counties dont have the Swedish font (NAME_2)

```
ID_0 ISO NAME_0 ID_1         NAME_1 ID_2      NAME_2   HASC_2 CCN_2 CCA_2   TYPE_2    ENGTYPE_2
0  222 SWE Sweden    1 Ã–stergÃ¶tland    1   Ã–deshÃ¶g SE.OG.OD     0  <NA> Kommuner Municipality
1  222 SWE Sweden    1 Ã–stergÃ¶tland    2 Ã…tvidaberg SE.OG.AT     0  <NA> Kommuner Municipality
2  222 SWE Sweden    1 Ã–stergÃ¶tland    3     Boxholm SE.OG.BO     0  <NA> Kommuner Municipality
3  222 SWE Sweden    1 Ã–stergÃ¶tland    4   FinspÃ¥ng SE.OG.FI     0  <NA> Kommuner Municipality
4  222 SWE Sweden    1 Ã–stergÃ¶tland    5       Kinda SE.OG.KI     0  <NA> Kommuner Municipality
5  222 SWE Sweden    1 Ã–stergÃ¶tland    6  LinkÃ¶ping SE.OG.LI     0  <NA> Kommuner Municipality
  NL_NAME_2 VARNAME_2
0      <NA>      <NA>
1      <NA>      <NA>
2      <NA>      <NA>
3      <NA>      <NA>
4      <NA>      <NA>
```

How to work over that?

Comment: You may want to look into https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.0.3/topics/Encoding

Answer (score 1):

If you are in Sweden your system encoding is probably "latin1" and since you are reading in the shapefile without specifying the encoding of the text; R assumes that the encoding is your native system encoding ("latin1"). Try specifying the encoding as "UTF-8":

```
mapa <- readOGR(dsn=path.expand("C:/~/SWE_adm_shp"),
                layer="SWE_adm2",
                encoding="UTF-8")
```

Of course the reverse could also be possible (system encoding is UTF-8 and your file is latin-1), in which case this will work:

```
mapa <- readOGR(dsn=path.expand("C:/~/SWE_adm_shp"),
                layer="SWE_adm2",
                encoding="latin1")
```

You can read this for more details: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rgdal/vignettes/OGR_shape_encoding.pdf